# Program to set time on local computer using GPS data

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, time, gps

I have a laptop running Windows XP that does not connect to the Internet and I would like to use a USB GPS receiver as a time source to set the clock. Generally, the laptop will not have access to the open sky so getting a strong, multi-satellite connection is not likely.

Ideally, I would like to be able to have the program detect the GPS receiver and set the clock without intervention from the user.

Is what I'm seeking even feasible?

Comment: Commenting vs. answering because I'm no expert at this, but I down own several computers and an old school Garmin GPS that has a serial port interface. Programmatically I don't see why you couldn't do this - in my imagination, you'd write a Service that monitors the serial port then parses the GPS info for the time and sets it. Here's the data format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183

Comment: @MarkAllen I think this may be the way to go. I have identified the [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/) library for Visual Studio. I was hoping that someone had already invented the wheel so to speak.

Comment: There might be - if you search for 'GPS clock' or GPS PC time set there's some software out there. I have not tried this one, but it claims to be able to do it: http://www.visoracle.com/download/freeware/tools/cluv.html

Comment: @MarkAllen Thanks for that tip. I tried to download it from your link but had some trouble. I did eventually find it here: http://www.timetools.co.uk/atomic-clock/fw/gpsclock.zip